# How to do a hard fork and go to a previous block on the chain?

Tags: fork

Seems that I cannot find anything that explains how to do hard forks and revert the chain to previous block/state.

Comment: Can you please describe more what you plan to do after you revert to that previous block?

Pretty sure what you are describing could be done in the client by simply adding an `if` statement and do not allow the import of block `n + 1`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subalfred's cl state fork-off](https://hack-ink.github.io/subalfred/user/cli/state.html#command-state) command - it is more easy to use than `fork-off-substrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before but look at this document seem works
https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate